# hovering on text in html not changing image in css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, image

i am trying to change image when the user clicks on different text, my code is like below:

```js
$("#zubi a").hover(function() {
  $("#pic").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr('rel'));
});
```

```css
#pic.p1 {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/id/236/200/300");
}

#pic.p2 {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300");
}

#pic.p3 {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300");
}

#pic.p4 {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zubi" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">MEN'S WEAR</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a rel="p1" class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">WOMEN'S WEAR</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a rel="p2" class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">KID'S WEAR</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a rel="p3" class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">JEWELLERY</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a rel="p4" class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">OTHER</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-0 col-lg-2"><img id="pic" style="margin-left:37%;height:90px;" class="mw-100 mh-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/235/200/300" alt="pic" /></div>
</div>
```

on hovering on the text, the image is not changing. can anyone please tell me what is wrong here, thanks in advance

Comment: 1. No jQuery, 2 same image - I added jQuery to your code, but it is still the same image

Comment: @mplungjan the first image is different, rest i just gave an example

Comment: Your code seems to work when I change the image to 5 different ones and add jQuery

Comment: @mplungjan i am not able to add jquery to my website, its making my complete website mislaligned, can you please tell me a solution

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: You are using jQuery code  - that will only work if you add `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` to the head too. Make sure you do not have more than one jQuery script tag

Comment: "I am not able to add jquery to my website"  that is highly unlikely. Just adding a script tag does not change a site unless the site is already using jQuery and you adding the tag activates it. If that is the case then you already had a huge amount of errors in the console

Comment: @mplungjan i tried , stll the jquery is making my website misaligned, is there anyway to take only that function code from jquery

Comment: @mplungjan actually i have used an html template, so it already have some jquery code, so when i am adding jquery cdn, my website not woring, is there any alternate solution with css to do the same?

Comment: If you already have jQuery, then your code should work when you use dfifferent images. Perhaps you just need to wrap your code. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in jQuery that can "misalign" a site unless there is inactive jQuery code that suddenly gets activated or old jQuery that is deprecated and works poorly with a new jQuery library.

If your template already has jQuery, then the code should work as soon as you use different images.

Perhaps all you need is to wrap

```
$(function() {
  $("#zubi a").hover(function() {
    $("#pic").removeClass().addClass($(this).attr('rel'));
  });
});
```

If not then here is the code you posted in vanilla JS. Note I changed rel to data-rel

```js
document.getElementById("zubi").addEventListener("mouseover", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
    const pic = document.getElementById("pic")
    pic.className="";
    pic.classList.add(tgt.dataset.rel);
  }
});
```

```css
#pic.p1 {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/id/236/200/300");
}

#pic.p2 {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300");
}

#pic.p3 {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/id/238/200/300");
}

#pic.p4 {
  content: url("https://picsum.photos/id/239/200/300");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="zubi" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">MEN'S WEAR</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a data-rel="p1" class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">WOMEN'S WEAR</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a data-rel="p2" class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">KID'S WEAR</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a data-rel="p3" class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">JEWELLERY</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2 mt-3 pb-3"><a data-rel="p4" class="dropdown-item" href="category.html">OTHER</a></div>
  <div class="col-md-0 col-lg-2"><img id="pic" style="margin-left:37%;height:90px;" class="mw-100 mh-100" src="https://picsum.photos/id/235/200/300" alt="pic" /></div>
</div>
```